# How to get humand readble month from django date field

Tags: django

I have defined month field in django models as:

```
from django.utils.dates import MONTHS

class Month(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField(choices=MONTHS.items(), blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.month)
```

At the moment when I try to get output for the months, I'm getting integer for month like 1, 2, 3 ... 12. How can I get literal or human readable months like January, February etc. I can see its there because I can see them in admin tab.

**EDIT:**

Anyone coming here for this kind of question. I'm able to get it working by using [get_month_display() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) built into django.

```
months_list = Month.objects.all()
for month in month_list:
    print(month.get_month_display())
```

Comment: See [get_FOO_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not OP but that is baller! TIL thanks! :)

Comment: What happens if you change it to MONTHS.values()?

Comment: @dfundako, I think it will not fly as a `month` is an integer field and it'll probably fail when saving, because the select will have string as values instead of numbers.

Comment: @KonradLyda When you run MONTHS.items() it returned a dict. values() came back with the string month names when I tested it out.

Comment: @dfundako I tried values but I get error that:   'Month' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman I've got it working through get_month_display()

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a list of tuples as a `choices` to the `models.IntegerField`

```
choices = [(k, v) for k, v in MONTHS.items()]
class Month(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField(choices=choices, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Calendar Python library

i.e `calendar.month_name[4]` -> 'April'

Reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name)